# eclipse plugin TextEditorMessages cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add button like "Add Bookmark...", to implemetion "my bookmark" cause of eclipse book plugin can not export And import ,

I have put popmenu in java editor, but when I use "TextEditorMessages" class ,it can not resolved,But I have import "org.eclipse.core.runtime" dependencies, and eclipse can navigation
[image: eclipseCanFeelClass]

look at picture
[image: successLabel]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the TextEditMessages class from the org.eclipse.text plugin.  Try adding org.eclipse.text to your plugin dependencies, changing the class name, and doing an organize imports.

A good way to search for base Eclipse classes is to open the Plug-ins View, select plugins you are interested in (I just do all plugins), and Right Click->Add to Java Search...

That'll let you to Open Type (ctrl-o) to search for any class from your base Eclipse.

Comment: not TextEditMessages ,my action extends from AbstractRulerActionDelegate and override method "createAction" , this method has two para, 
ITextEditor editor, IVerticalRulerInfo rulerInfo
this code I copy from
org.eclipse.jdt.ui plugin.xml ---org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BookmarkRulerAction

Comment: Are you sure your Eclipse versions are the same?  That is, did you copy source from an Eclipse version that isn't your PDE target platform version?

Comment: Yes, Import Eclipse Self Plug-ins And Fragments, from "import" menu,
thank you reply ,I find method to debug Eclipse Self "add Bookmark",
god,Dev a Plugin So Difficult !!

Comment: It's a steep learning curve, but there are lots of good howtos out there.  Don't give up!